# When I try to join meshes they mess up or turn transparent

Tags: mesh, transparency

I am trying to make a hair mesh for sims and every time I join the meshes [image: after the meshes are joined it looks like this], it deletes parts or turns transparent

Comment: May be there are modifiers on one of the meshes.

Comment: Okay so I figured out how to remove all modifiers but I am still having the same problem. Any more suggestions or things I could check for?

Comment: You can share your blend files here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ So the forumers can help easier.